What is the title of a movie in which a Japanese man cuts off his own finger?
Many years ago, I saw a very good action movie. Close to the end of the film many men are sitting at a large formal singing table.
As punishment for breaking the rules, one of the men agrees to cut off his own finger.
Yubitsume (ee-oo-b-ee-t-s-oo-m-eh-ee) is a ritualistic practice in which members of the Japanese mafia, or yakuza, amputate their left little finger.
What is the title of a movie is which Yubitsume is depicted?

Do you think there is only one such movie? Just check tv tropes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Yubitsume

To help us narrow this down (as there are many instances of this scene in many movies) please review Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions

Showdown in Little Tokyo

It is not quite close to the end though but pretty much in the middle (at around 40 minutes).

As well as "black rain" and some others...

One of the best such scenes was at the end of The Yakuza (1974) but it's obviously not the film the questioner is thinking of since the setting is different.
